# Download objects using UICollectionview while scrolling the colllectionview at the sametime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm working on application to download files throw a collectionView using objective c.

The download start after clicking in the cell "each cell present object to be downloaded", the download operation works fine, but there is a problem in the progress bar of the download when you scroll down while the download not finished yet, the progress bar go to another cell while it download other object in the background.

I wonder if any one face issue like this before and could help me to fix it.

Update:(adding the Code)

NSString * key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", odbook.storyID]; NSString * value = [[LibGlobals getNowDownloaingDictionary] valueForKey:key];

if (value == nil) 
{ MACircleProgressIndicator *downloadSlider = [[MACircleProgressIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bg_Image.frame];

downloadSlider.center = cell.bg_Image.center; downloadSlider.tag = odbook.storyID;

[cell.bg_Image.superview addSubview:downloadSlider];

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: My guess is that you have a reuse of cells issue. But without code, that's quite hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: this is the download Code that add the progress bar to cell: @user80755 
NSString * key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", odbook.storyID];
        NSString * value = [[LibGlobals getNowDownloaingDictionary] valueForKey:key];
   
        if (value == nil) {
             
            MACircleProgressIndicator *downloadSlider = [[MACircleProgressIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bg_Image.frame];
            downloadSlider.center = cell.bg_Image.center;
            downloadSlider.tag = odbook.storyID;
            [cell.bg_Image.superview addSubview:downloadSlider];

Comment: @Larme chick out this man

Comment: Try to remove view before each new cell is constructed. Place this code before if (value == nil) for (id subview in cell.bg_Image.superview) {
        if ([subview isMemberOfClass:MACircleProgressIndicator]) {
           [subview removefromsuperview];
        }
}

Comment: @MohammadOthman: Please edit your question with your code. In comment, it's not readable.

Comment: Since you are using custom cell, already put the progress bar. Don't add it as subview (since it's custom cell already), if not, remove the view in the reusing, cells are reused.

Comment: @Larme thank you man, it was a great idea and resolved everything